# InfoPath 2010 save and continue issue

Tags: infopath, save

Hi i have created InfoPath form 2010 with save and continue . When I am saving for the first time and continuing my work in the form it works fine. If i make the changes again immediately it throws an error saying

" The form cannot be submitted.
Save Conflict.

Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."

Can some one suggest on what could be the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't submit your changes if you do 'Save & Continue' but if that is the requirement you should run a data connection again before you hit submit button to refresh all your fields. The error that you see is due to the changes other users are making while you are updating similar fields. When you run a data connection before you submit it will refresh the last updated fields and submit.

Comment: Hi Noman, thanks for the comments. I am the only one who is editing it no other user is editing the form. I am not submitting the form I am clicking save and continue and will remain on the form, problem is when i do the changes again while the form is still open and try to click on the saveNcontinue it throws this error.Which data connection should i run? Can you elaborate the steps for me please.